# Arduino EEProm.h code

Tags: c++

What does this bit of code do?

```
EERef( const int index )
        : index( index ) {}
```

It's inside a struct such as this...

```
/***
EERef class.

This object references an EEPROM cell.
Its purpose is to mimic a typical byte of RAM, however its storage is the EEPROM.
This class has an overhead of two bytes, similar to storing a pointer to an EEPROM cell.
***/

struct EERef{

EERef( const int index )
    : index( index ) {}

//Access/read members.
uint8_t operator*() const
{ 
    return eeprom_read_byte( (uint8_t*) index ); 
}
operator const uint8_t() const       
{ 
    return **this; 
}
```

..... etc....

I've totally forgotten my C++. Someone jog my memory please?

Comment: Please do not tag C++ questions with the C tag. The C tag is for C questions.

Comment: _"I've totally forgotten my C++."_ Then pick up your textbook and remind yourself. Prior research is required for questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

> What does this bit of code do?
>
> EERef( const int index ) : index( index ) {}

That particular line of code is a constructor for `struct EERef` that takes a parameter and initializes the `index` member of `EERef` with the parameter value.

For reference: [Constructors and Initializer Lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)